# KeyError: 'users' when using tweepy to scrape the twitter data, how can I bypass such error?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I am going to scrape the information from twitter using the academic account through the tweepy package, it works fine for some months but in particular months it showed "KeyError: 'users'". How can I bypass the error?

Here is the code that I execute;

```
tweets = []

for i,j in zip(start_time,end_time):
    print(i)
    print(j)
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                     query = 'ไทรอยด์ -is:retweet lang:th',
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                                     expansions = ['author_id', 'geo.place_id'],
                                     start_time = i,
                                     end_time = j):
                                     
        time.sleep(1)
        tweets.append(response)
    result = []
    user_dict = {}
    
    for response in tweets:
        
        for user in response.includes['users']:
            user_dict[user.id] = {'username': user.username, 
                                  'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],
                                  'tweets': user.public_metrics['tweet_count'],
                                  'description': user.description,
                                  'location': user.location
                                 }
```

Results:

```
2020-08-01T00:00:00Z
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z
Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 30 seconds.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13308/265973239.py in <module>
     23     for response in tweets:
     24         # Take all of the users, and put them into a dictionary of dictionaries with the info we want to keep
---> 25         for user in response.includes['users']:
     26             user_dict[user.id] = {'username': user.username, 
     27                                   'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],

KeyError: 'users'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code use an empty default value so that it doesn't fail if the `users` field doesn't exist:

```py
for user in response.includes.get('users', ''):
     # do something with user
```

This fixes only the symptom, however. To find out the reason why the field doesn't exist, you could try to check for the keys before using them (e.g. `if 'users' in response.includes`) and print out the full response data to get more information. One hint is the rate limiting message you have received.

Comment: Thanks @Jan Wilamowski -- so I print the result first and convert to .csv format. I did not get the tweets from the whole period as I expected. Thus, I readjusted the time frame to avoid the error.